# retrieve data from postgresql with php and stored the value in a variable

Tags: php, postgresql

I'm trying the code below to retrieve data from postgresql with php and stored the value in a variable.

I have a table named: Menu with 3 columns named: name, rating and numofratings.

One of the records is:
    name = Pasta
    rating = 4
    numofratings = 3

And I want to retrieve the
rating = 4
numofratings = 3

and stored those numbers in 2 variables: value and value2 to use the values.

This is what I tried but it is not printing the values, so I'm doing something wrong and don't know what it is.

Any help would be appreciated.

THANKS

```
<?php   

$db = pg_connect('host=localhost dbname=test user=myuser password=mypass');


    $query = "SELECT rating, numofratings FROM menu where name = 'Pasta'";
    $result = pg_query($query);
    if (!$result) {
        echo "Problem with query " . $query . "<br/>";
        echo pg_last_error();
        exit();
    }

$myrow = pg_fetch_assoc($result); 
    $value == $myrow[rating];
    $value2 == $myrow[numofratings];

    echo "$value, $value2";

 ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`==` is the equality check operator. To assign a value to a variable, you should use the `=` operator:

```
$value = $myrow[rating];
$value2 = $myrow[numofratings];
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
$myrow = pg_fetch_assoc($result); 
$value = $myrow[rating];
$value2 = $myrow[numofratings];
```

You're using ==, which is not assignment, but comparison. So your code is basically doing

```
$myrow = pg_fetch_assoc($result); 
false;
false;
print ", ";
```

...since those two variables never actually get assigned or even exist at all.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [PDO prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php)

```
$sql = "SELECT rating, numofratings FROM menu where name = :name";
$pdo = new PDO('pgsql:dbname=mydb;host=localhost;user=myuser;password=mypass');
if ($con = $pdo->prepare($sql)) {
    $con->execute([
        ':name'=>'Pasta'
    ]);
    $r = $con->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    if(!empty($r)){
        $val1 = $r['rating'];
        $val2 = $r['numofratings'];
    }
}
```

You will want to put quotes arround `['rating']` and `['numofratings']` because PHP will throw a fit if you don't.

Try printing out the errors to see what's wrong with your code.

```
//At the top of the php page
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```